# How to create a CSR using Google Cloud KMS?

Tags: csr, hsm, google-cloud-kms

I want to use Google Cloud KMS for asymmetric signing. To complete setup with the destination provider I need to send them a CSR signed with the private key stored in Google. I've found some examples of doing this using Java or Go but I don't need to do it programatically and I don't know those languages anyway. Ideally I'm looking for something command line based using the SDK.

Comment: More specifically: Create certificate request generated from the HSM system which must meet the requirements of FIPS 140-2 Level 2. The request can be accepted in .P1, .b64 or .pem format and must include the Distinguished Name (DN). The key size must be set to RSA Key Size 2048.